# iterate over large amount of data in fragment shader

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm trying to iterate over a large amount of data in my fragment shader in webgl. I want to pass a lot of data to it and then iterate on each pass of the fragment shader.  I'm having some issues doing that though.  My ideas were the following:
1. pass the data in uniforms to the frag shader, but I can't send very much data that way.
2. use a buffer to send data as I do verts to the vert shader and then use a varying to send data to the frag shader. unfortunately this seems to involve some issues. (a) varying's interpolate between vectors and I think that'll cause issues with my code (although perhaps this is unavoidable ) (b) more importantly, I don't know how to iterate over the data i pass to my fragment shader. I'm already using a buffer for my 3d point coordinates, but how does webgl handle a second buffer and data coming through it.

*** I mean to say, in what order is data fetched from each buffer (my first buffer containing 3d coordinates and the second buffer I'm trying to add)? lastly, as stated above, if i want to iterate over all the data passed for every pass of the fragment shader, how can i do that? ***

i've already tried using a uniform array and iterate over that in my fragment shader but i ran into limitations I believe since there is a relatively small size limit for uniforms. I'm currently trying the second method mentioned above.

```
//pseudo code

vertexCode = `

attribute vec4 3dcoords;
varying vec4 3dcoords;

??? ??? my_special_data;


void main(){...}

`


fragCode = `

varying vec4 3dcoords;

void main(){

...

// perform math operation on 3dcoords for all values in my_special_data variable and store in variable my_results

if( my_results ... ){

gl_FragColor += ...;

}

`
```

Comment: To iterate over lots of data pass the data in as a texture. A texture is really just a 2D array of data that you can randomly access.

Comment: yeah that's what I just read but I can't seem to find any simple clean documentation on that.  Could you possibly provide some pseudo code or at least tell me how I input the data into the fragShader with a small code snippet? I've tried using sampleCube or sample2D, but I think my implementation was incorrect and I just kept getting errors. Oh, and can I write to this texture if i want to add more data at run time?

Comment: also, how can I access a random element from the array in my fragShader? pages like the following don't seem to mention how to access elements of the texture: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL

Comment: There's a GLSL function, `texture2D`. It takes a UV coordinate. Use the UV coordinate lookup a value from the texture.. Also [read better tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org) ;)

Comment: ok cool, does using textures allow sending signed integers? I'm managed to send some texture data but I need negative integers.

Comment: webgl2 allows signed integer textures. webgl1 only allows normalized textures or optionally float16 and float32

Comment: ok much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textures in WebGL are random access 2D arrays of data so you can use them to read lots of data
Example:

```js
const width = 256;
const height = 256;
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D tex;
const int width = ${width};
const int height = ${height};
void main() {
  vec4 sums = vec4(0);
  for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
      vec2 xy = (vec2(x, y) + 0.5) / vec2(width, height);
      sums += texture2D(tex, xy);
    }
  }
  gl_FragColor = sums;
}
`;

function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  // check if we can make floating point textures
  const ext1 = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
  if (!ext1) {
    return alert('need OES_texture_float');
  }
  // check if we can render to floating point textures
  const ext2 = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_color_buffer_float');
  if (!ext2) {
    return alert('need WEBGL_color_buffer_float');
  }

  // make a 1x1 pixel floating point RGBA texture and attach it to a framebuffer
  const framebufferInfo = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl, [
    { type: gl.FLOAT, },
  ], 1, 1);
  
  // make random 256x256 texture
  const data = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    data[i] = Math.random() * 256;
  }
  const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    src: data,
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
  });
  
  // compile shaders, link, lookup locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  // create a buffer and put a 2 unit
  // clip space quad in it using 2 triangles
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
        -1, -1,
         1, -1,
        -1,  1,
        -1,  1,
         1, -1,
         1,  1,
      ],
    },
  });

  // render to the 1 pixel texture
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferInfo.framebuffer);
  // set the viewport for 1x1 pixels
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    tex,
  });
  const offset = 0;
  const count = 6;
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, count);

  // read the result
  const pixels = new Float32Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, pixels);
  console.log('webgl sums:', pixels);
  const sums = new Float32Array(4);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
      sums[j] += data[i + j] / 255;
    }
  }
  console.log('js sums:', sums);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gawd I hate SO's search. I know I've written this answer before. Spending 20 minutes looking but couldn't find it